# affiliation error in ACS journal template

Tags: errors

I am using ACS template for a research article. I'm having trouble getting several affiliations for authors. For instance,

```
\documentclass[
%journal=ancac3, % for ACS Nano
%journal=acbcct, % for ACS Chem. Biol.
journal=jacsat, % for undefined journal
manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}

\newcommand*{\mycommand}[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}

\author{One}
\author{Two}
\affiliation[A]
{A, address A}
\affiliation[B]
{B, address B}

\title[\texttt{achemso} demonstration]{A demonstration of the 
\textsf{achemso} \LaTeX\ class}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image]

I would like that authors One and Two have both A and B affiliations. Do you know how can I solve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\altaffiliation` to set this up, for example

```
\documentclass[
%journal=ancac3, % for ACS Nano
%journal=acbcct, % for ACS Chem. Biol.
journal=jacsat, % for undefined journal
manuscript=article]{achemso}

\author{One}
\altaffiliation{B, address B}
\affiliation[A]
{A, address A}

\author{Two}
\altaffiliation{B, address B}
\affiliation[A]
{A, address A}

\title[\texttt{achemso} demonstration]{A demonstration of the 
\textsf{achemso} \LaTeX\ class}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! In this way, you need to repeat the affiliations for every author. Is there any way to avoid doing that?